# not able to reset primary key numbering in SQLite table

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to use "DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE" SQL statement to reset the numbering system for _ID rowId that is the primary key for the table.   This makes the first row as 1 again for the table.  I was able to do this with no problems in a java desktop app, however in this android app it is not working.  any ideas?

EDIT: i found and fixed the runtime error. so I removed the stacktrace from the question. that part is fixed however, now it will not reset the numbering of the rows.  when i display the database it shows the same numbering.  for example if i delete row 3, then that missing row 3 is still missing after the "DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE is used.  is there something else that i neeed to do after running that SQL statement?  like reaload the database?  i did not have to do that with the java app.

from Database class

```
 public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "my_database";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "my_table";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String _ID = "_id";
    public static final String TABLE_STRING = "table_string";
    public static final String PAGE = "page";
    public static final String VERSION = "version";

  //create table MY_DATABASE (_ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  
        TABLE_STRING + " TEXT, " + PAGE + " TEXT, " + VERSION + " TEXT);";

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    Context context;
```

from the Database class

```
public void resetRowNumbers(){

             sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME =
          '" + MYDATABASE_TABLE + "'");
         }
```

from the MainActivity class

```
 public void resetRowNumbering(){
    db = new Database(getApplication());
    db.openToWrite();
    db.resetRowNumbers();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME =my_table` does not have the required quotes that your code seems to have, so you may have changed the code since the error message. Could you add the current message?

Comment: i just updated the question,  no more stacktrace errors on runtime,  but another problem.

Comment: If there's still data in the table, SQLite won't start the sequence no from 1 even if you clean out sqlite_sequence. Did you clean out the table at the same time you deleted the sequence?

Comment: no, i did not clean out the table,  i will try that now

Comment: yes, you are correct, I was only able to get it to restart numbering from 1 after deleting out all the rows in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code I found that works:

```
 sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM '" + MYDATABASE_TABLE + "'");
 sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME =
  '" + MYDATABASE_TABLE + "'");
```

The answer is for the part of the code that had a * in between DELETE and FROM for the first SQL statement above. For Android using the * does not work.  It results in a runtime error.  This despite the fact that it is sometimes shown in internet examples for SQL statements. It does not work with Android's version of SQLite.

the correct statement is:

```
 "DELETE FROM '" + MYDATABASE_TABLE + "'"
```

this deletes all rows from a table.  then after that use:

```
  "DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + MYDATABASE_TABLE + "'"
```

which will reset the primary key numbering to start from 1 again when you enter a new row.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you should not delete the sequence but reset it to zero:

```
"UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = 0 WHERE name=  '" + MYDATABASE_TABLE + "'"
```

But generally said, and you may know this, it's almost never agood idea to reset a sequence.

Comment: thank you for this comment, I will try it and see what happens